# Generate export excel-table using EPPlus.Core

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, export

I want to create service which will be generating excel-table from my stored procedure. I'm looking to https://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-excel-asp-net-core-2-razor-pages/ where it is work for razor page directly, but i need to create service (in my business layer and provide it to controller).

I faced with problem that in this tutorial it is return `IActionResult` from function:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostExport()
{
    //logic
    return File(memory, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", sFileName);
}
```

Please see https://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-excel-asp-net-core-2-razor-pages/ for mode details.

I tried to write this code:

```
public class ExportService
{      
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public ExportService(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public async Task OnPostExport(int year)
    {
        //logic
        return File(memory, "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
        officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", sFileName);
    }
```

It does not work because "return File" - functional from PageModel how it work in tutorial. I want to return file to controller from my service. What type should I return from my `OnPostExport` function? I will be grateful for any information and ideas that I need to do.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `byte[]`. You can save the EPPlus file to a byte array instead of to an actual file using `MemoryStream` and then return that byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `File`, it's the base method from `ControllerBase` which will return `FileContentResult`. If you prefer using `File`, you could implement the code from [FileResult variants](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/8d66f104f7f2ca42ee8b21f75b0e2b3e1abe2e00/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L1082).

IMO, I would suggest you return `byte[]` from `public async Task OnPostExport(int year)` and then construct the response `File` like

```
public async Task<byte[]> OnPostExport(int year)
{
    //logic
    return filebytearray;
}


var dt = await _exportService.OnPostExport(1);
return File(dt, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", sFileName);
```